# Using Taylor Polynomial for Estimating Error

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Need some help in this question!
***Let $f(x,y)$ be $C^3$ in the open set $A\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ and let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a point of $A$. Proof that there are an open ball $B$ of center $(x_0,y_0)$, with $B\subset A$, and  a number $M>0$ such that, for all $(x,y)\in B$
$$|f(x,y)-P_2(x,y)|\leq M \|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|^3$$
 where $P_2(x,y)$ is the Taylor polynomial of order 2 of $f$ around $(x_0,y_0)$.***

This appeared to me like an exercise. Is this a famous result? Has some special name? I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: I accept recommendation of books or sites.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of Taylor's theorem - something like the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) should be helpful.